# If I have a next.js app with thousands of rows of sensitive data, should I be doing getStaticProps?

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

Should I be doing server side rendering? My understanding is that a json would be stored on the CDN, so will it be safe there?

Comment: Depends. The [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/data-fetching/get-static-props#when-should-i-use-getstaticprops) clearly states the data should be: publicly cacheable (not user-specific). What does "sensitive data" mean in your case?

Comment: like for instance, health information, company data related to their business etc.

Comment: Then I'd recommend Next.js' server side components and SSR rather then SSG. This will keep you logic on the server and only send the generated HTML to the client. Also if this application was to be used by more then one company, authentication and authorization would ensure data protection.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice. In terms of performance is SSR the same as regular frontend api call to backend for data or better?

Comment: Really depends on the deployment and speed of your backend. Vercel is quite optimized for next.js applications (obviously)